# The various ways to get the Internal energy of a Fermi gas applied to a simplified neutron star

Tags: energy, neutron-stars

I'm working on the ultra-simplified model of a neutron star where it is represented as a non-relativistic ideal Fermi gas. All textbooks I had a look at give the well-know formula for the internal kinetic energy of an ideal fermi gas at temperature 0K, which reads $$U=\frac{3}{5}NE_f,$$ where $E_f$ is the Fermi energy and $N$ the number of neutrons. My problem is that this result is obtained following different ways depending of the reference you look at, and I like to know if one of them is better, which is the most rigorous, physically sound.

For example, in the book by Povh et al., "Particles and Nuclei", 6th Edition, Springer, I find at page 247 that [image: Povh et al. page 247, Eq. 17.9]

and in this equation, the only thing which relates to the Fermi gas is $p_F$. After that, the internal energy is obtained stating that $U = N \langle E_{kin} \rangle$.

On the other hand, for example in this document: [http://www.physics.drexel.edu/~bob/Term_Reports/Whitehead_hw1.pdf](http://www.physics.drexel.edu/%7Ebob/Term_Reports/Whitehead_hw1.pdf),
the internal energy is obtained from the equation
[image: Equations 5, 6, and 7 from http://www.physics.drexel.edu/~bob/Term_Reports/Whitehead_hw1.pdf]

I also found another way which looks like this:
$$\langle E \rangle = \frac{\int_0^{E_F} E (dn/dE) dE}{\int_0^{E_F} (dn/dE) dE},$$
and in that case, the expression obtained for $dn/dE$ obeys $dn/dE \propto \sqrt{E}$, which allows to obtain the same result as above.

So all these approaches lead to the same result $U=3/5\,N\,E_f,$ but they all start from different points. I'm aware of this topic ([Total energy of a simple fermi gas](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/286941/total-energy-of-a-simple-fermi-gas)), but I'd appreciate anyway some help to make sense of all of this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For the context of neutron stars (and a toy model for their equation of state) I like the derivation put forward by N. K. Glendenning in his book [Compact Stars](https://link.springer.com/book/9780387989778) p. 92ff. It shares some similarities with the answer to [Total energy of a simple fermi gas](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/286942/120730). For the remainder of this answer I use a natural unit system with $\hbar=c=1$.

Lets consider a degenerate ideal Fermi gas: meaning interactions between fermions are ignored (the ideal part) and assuming that all quantum states are filled up to a given energy -- the so called Fermi energy -- (the degenerate part). One can usually assume degeneracy for low temperatures: $T\ll E_\mathrm{f}=\sqrt{k_\mathrm{f}^2+m^2}$ -- a good assumption for cold isolated neutron stars. Given these assumptions the number density $n$ (number of fermions $N$ in a volume $V$) is given by
$$n=\frac{N}{V}=\frac{1}{V}\sum_{\vec{n}}f(\vec{k}_n)\rightarrow\frac{1}{V}\int\mathrm{d}^3k \,f(\vec{k})\frac{\partial(n_1,n_2,n_3)}{\partial(k_1,k_2,k_3)}\tag{1},$$
with the occupation number (all momentum states are occupied with spin up and spin down fermions up to the Fermi surface $k_\mathrm{f}$)
$$f(\vec{k})=2\,\Theta(k_\mathrm{f}-|\vec{k}|). \tag{2}$$
The arrow in Eq. (1) indicates the thermodynamic limit -- here the limit of a large system. The wave vector $\vec{k}_n$ inside a box of length $L=V^{1/3}$ is given by
$$\vec{k}_n=\frac{2\pi}{L}\vec{n}, \tag{3}$$
for a given one particle state $|\vec{n}\rangle$. Using Eq. (3) we can compute
$$
\frac{\partial(n_1,n_2,n_3)}{\partial(k_1,k_2,k_3)}\equiv\frac{\partial n_1}{\partial k_1}\frac{\partial n_2}{\partial k_2}\frac{\partial n_3}{\partial k_3}=\frac{V}{(2\pi)^3}.
$$
and ultimately we can compute the number density using spherical coordinates:
$$
n=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_0^{k_\mathrm{f}}\mathrm{d}k\,k^2=\frac{k_\mathrm{f}^3}{3\pi^2}. \tag{4}
$$

Similar to the expression for the number density the general expression for the energy density $\epsilon$ reads (in the thermodynamic limit)
$$\begin{align} 
\epsilon&=\frac{1}{V}\int\mathrm{d}^3k \,\sqrt{\vec{k}\cdot\vec{k}+m^2}\,f(\vec{k})\frac{\partial(n_1,n_2,n_3)}{\partial(k_1,k_2,k_3)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_0^{k_\mathrm{f}}\mathrm{d}k\,k^2\sqrt{k^2+m^2}. \tag{5}
\end{align} 
$$
So far we have not talked about any kinematic limitations (like a relativistic or non-relativistic limit). In the non-relativistic limit momenta (here especially the Fermi momentum $k_\mathrm{f}$) are small compared to the particle masses $m$, hence to compute the integral for the energy density (5) we expand the integrand for small momenta in $k/m$ up to next-to-leading order:
$$\begin{align} 
\epsilon&=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_0^{k_\mathrm{f}}\mathrm{d}k\,k^2\sqrt{k^2+m^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_0^{k_\mathrm{f}}\mathrm{d}k\,k^2\left(m k^2+\frac{k^4}{2 m}+\ldots\right)\\
&=\frac{k_\mathrm{f}^3}{3\pi^2}\left(m+\frac{3 k_\mathrm{f}^2}{10 m}+\ldots\right)
\\
&=n\left(m+\frac{3}{5}\frac{\mathrm{k}_f^2}{2 m}+\ldots\right), \tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
where we used Eq. (4) in the last step. Identifying $E_\mathrm{f}\equiv\frac{\mathrm{k}_f^2}{2 m}$ as the non-relativistic Fermi energy we arrive at the energy density of the non-relativistic ideal degenerate Fermi gas
$$
\epsilon_\mathrm{nr}= n m + \frac{3}{5}n E_\mathrm{f},\tag{7}
$$
from which we can identify the internal kinetic energy $U$ in a volume $V$
$$
U_\mathrm{nr}=V(\epsilon_\mathrm{nr}-n m)=\frac{3}{5} V n E_\mathrm{f} = \frac{3}{5}N E_\mathrm{f}.
$$

For the sake of completeness the pressure $p$ can be computed using the usual thermodynamic relationship
$$
p=-\frac{\partial E}{\partial V} = n^2\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\frac{\epsilon}{n}=n\frac{\partial\epsilon}{\partial n}-\epsilon,\tag{8}
$$
which in the non-relativistic case yields the known result
$$
p_\mathrm{nr}=\frac{2}{5}n E_\mathrm{f}\tag{9}.
$$

Using the expressions for the non-relativistic pressure and energy one can construct polytropes $p=K \epsilon^\gamma$ which are sometimes used in toy model calculation for compact stars. In the non-relativistic limit we recover the characteristic polytropic index $\gamma_\mathrm{nr}=5/3$. For neutron stars (and white dwarfs) the opposite limit (ultra relativistic $k\gg m$) is usually considered. An equation of state combining both limits could also be used.

But these simplified equations of state yield unrealistically light neutron stars with maximum masses below 0.9 solar masses. For white dwarfs the situation is different since there most of the pressure is actually generated by an ultra relativistic electron gas and one can obtain a sensible estimate for the maximum mass of around 1.4 solar masses for typical white dwarfs.

For more details I recommend the section *3.9 White Dwarfs and Neutron Stars* in Glendennings book.

**EDIT:** In light of the first comment to this answer: I do not think the approaches to compute $U$ mentioned in the question differ in their essence. They differ mainly in notation and arguably rigor/depth. All either use or compute the expressions of Eqs. (4), (5) and (6). The second one from [Whitehead_hw1.pdf](http://www.physics.drexel.edu/%7Ebob/Term_Reports/Whitehead_hw1.pdf) is non-relativistic and therefore uses $E=p^2/(2m)$ from the get go. The first and third one are the same just using different integration variables: they are related by switching coordinates from $p$ to $E=p^2/(2m)$. Integrals over momentum $p$ or wave vector $n$ are also just related by switching variables using Eq. (3). And wether to compute $U$ or $\langle E_\mathrm{kin} \rangle$ is also somewhat preference since $U=N \langle E_\mathrm{kin} \rangle$ (in words the average kinetic energy $\langle E_\mathrm{kin} \rangle$ is just the total kinetic energy divided by the total number of particles) and note that $N$ is given by Eq. (4) times $V$. In the expression for $\langle E_\mathrm{kin} \rangle$ given in the question spherical coordinates are used and several factors are already canceled. Writing out $\langle E_\mathrm{kin} \rangle=U/N$ with the expressions and integrals discussed would give the mentioned formula. Cutting through notation and nomenclature I fail to see conceptual differences.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. There is still something I'd like to understand, which is the main point of my question: why is that so many ways can be found to derive this U = 3/5 N Ef relation? The one you describe is certainly the most rigorous, but does that mean the others I mention are just wrong?

Comment: @JB75 fair enough: I edited the answer to give some remarks but in summary: I fail to recognize fundamental differences between the mentioned 'approaches'. They just use different notations and assume a non-relativistic dispersion relation $E=p^2/(2m)$ from the beginning (which is fine if you only want to compute non-relativisticly).

Comment: Thanks again! I also thought at one point that on can take whatever method and find the same result. I guess the problem I have is related to the fact that if I take the expression for $|p| = hn/2V^{1/3}$ from Whitehead_hw1.pdf, and use it with the last expression I gave for $\langle E \rangle$, I don't get the factor 3/5... So I guess it's not possible to mix between the different methods, I just have to take one and stick to it from the beginning to the end.